# Check language tag on current page with php?

Tags: php

I want to echo the language of the current page.
Lets say I have this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl-pl" lang="pl-pl" dir="ltr">
```

I want something like this: If language of current page is polish, echo "polish".

Comment: In php? why? how is the page printed? it seems a way easier javascript task here.

Comment: The question shows basic misconception of how PHP works for serving web pages. It's stateless an it's not possible to read HTML via PHP. Of course you can send it back using JS but that's an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this for joomla but found out there is a `$this->language` tag that solves the problem.